# Cannot use table 'AspNetUserRoles' for entity type 'IdentityUserRole<string>' since it is being used for entity type 'AspNetUserRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting below the error

> Cannot use table 'AspNetUserRoles' for entity type
> 'IdentityUserRole' since it is being used for entity type
> 'AspNetUserRole (Dictionary<string, object>)' and potentially other
> entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key
> to 'IdentityUserRole' on the primary key properties and
> pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to
> 'AspNetUserRoles'.

I am using Database first approach. Please find my Db Context File below:-

```
public partial class EmployeeContext : IdentityDbContext<UserDetail>
{
    public EmployeeContext()
    {
    }

    public EmployeeContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaim> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserToken> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<TblEmployeeSalary> TblEmployeeSalaries { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Tblemployee> Tblemployees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName, "RoleNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(256);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoleClaim>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId, "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Role).WithMany(p => p.AspNetRoleClaims).HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail, "EmailIndex");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName, "UserNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.Roles).WithMany(p => p.Users)
                .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                    "AspNetUserRole",
                    r => r.HasOne<AspNetRole>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("RoleId"),
                    l => l.HasOne<AspNetUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId"),
                    j =>
                    {
                        j.HasKey("UserId", "RoleId");
                        j.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
                        j.HasIndex(new[] { "RoleId" }, "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId");
                    });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserClaim>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId, "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserClaims).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogin>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId, "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserLogins).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserToken>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name });

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserTokens).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TblEmployeeSalary>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("tblEmployeeSalary");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Employee).WithMany(p => p.TblEmployeeSalaries)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_tblEmployeeSalary_tblemployee");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tblemployee>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("tblemployee_pkey");

            entity.ToTable("tblemployee");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            entity.Property(e => e.Department)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("department");
            entity.Property(e => e.Ename)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .HasColumnName("ename");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Unable to determine, what changes I need to make

Answer (score 2):

I create a cleaned-up version of the EmployeeContext, you can try it and tell me the result.

```
public partial class EmployeeContext : IdentityDbContext<UserDetail>
{
    public EmployeeContext()
    {
    }

    public EmployeeContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TblEmployeeSalary> TblEmployeeSalaries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tblemployee> Tblemployees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);  // This will handle all default Identity configurations

        // Removed AspNet* configurations because base.OnModelCreating handles them

        modelBuilder.Entity<TblEmployeeSalary>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("tblEmployeeSalary");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Employee)
                  .WithMany(p => p.TblEmployeeSalaries)
                  .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeeId)
                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                  .HasConstraintName("FK_tblEmployeeSalary_tblemployee");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tblemployee>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("tblemployee_pkey");

            entity.ToTable("tblemployee");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            entity.Property(e => e.Department)
                  .HasMaxLength(50)
                  .HasColumnName("department");
            entity.Property(e => e.Ename)
                  .HasMaxLength(100)
                  .HasColumnName("ename");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your provided DbContext, it appears that you are using Entity Framework Core with the Identity framework for user authentication. The issue you are encountering seems to be related to the configuration of the IdentityUserRole entity, which is used by Identity to manage the many-to-many relationship between users and roles.

In your code, you have already defined the AspNetUser and AspNetRole entities, but you seem to have a custom configuration for the AspNetUserRole entity using a dictionary-based approach. This might be causing the issue.

To resolve this issue, you should remove the custom configuration for AspNetUserRole and rely on the default configuration provided by Identity. Here are the steps you should follow:

1. Remove the custom configuration for AspNetUserRole from your OnModelCreating method. Specifically, remove this part of your code:

```js
entity.HasMany(d => d.Roles).WithMany(p => p.Users)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        "AspNetUserRole",
        r => r.HasOne<AspNetRole>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("RoleId"),
        l => l.HasOne<AspNetUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId"),
        j =>
        {
            j.HasKey("UserId", "RoleId");
            j.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
            j.HasIndex(new[] { "RoleId" }, "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId");
        });
```

Make sure that your OnModelCreating method does not include any custom configurations for AspNetUserRole.
After removing the custom configuration, you can rely on the default configuration provided by Identity. This should establish the necessary foreign key relationships between AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, and AspNetUserRoles.
Rebuild your application and run any necessary database migrations to apply the changes to your database schema.
By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the issue related to the AspNetUserRoles table and its relationship with AspNetUserRole. The default Identity configuration should handle this relationship correctly.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but now I am getting different error while adding migration: Cannot use table 'AspNetRoles' for entity type 'AspNetRole' since it is being used for entity type 'IdentityRole' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'AspNetRole' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'AspNetRoles'

Comment: @RahulAggarwal, you might need to delete your current migration and create a fresh one. It's possible that your existing migration is not aligned with the proposed modifications and is causing conflicts.

Comment: Even after deleting all migration it is giving me the same error